# Microsoft graph rest api v1.0: Access to B2C tenant users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to get user information, not only from Azure Active Directory, but also from Azure B2C Tenant Users. I was able to reproduce results for AAD users, but I couldn't find enough resource as for how to access to B2C Users (e.g. Gmail.com). I get this error when I swap to my desired clientid/clientsecret (fetched from Azure AD B2C - Application) in this project (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample):

> 'unsupported_response_type', error_description: 'AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application.

I couldn't find the recent resources helpful, as a lot of Azure component changed. I would greatly appreciate your kind guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to programatically CRUD B2C Users.

AADB2C has a documentation for same using AADGraph (and not using Microsoft Graph)

[Build user CRUD operations by using the Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#build-user-crud-operations-by-using-the-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

As of today,you must use the [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to manage users in an Azure AD B2C directory. This is different from the Microsoft Graph API. The sample you referred to is not appropriate for managing B2C tenant users.