# No Access Token received after receiving Authorization Code from B2C endpoint to access MS Graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

We have application registered in our B2C tenant and we are trying to read user's information after they login in the application using MS Graph SDK.

**C#**

```
var me = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

**Permission**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
```

We are able to get the access token from [login.microsoftonline.com](https://www.login.microsoftonline.com) using [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) **but not in .b2clogin.com**.

Below is the snippet of the code

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetUserAccessTokenByAuthorizationCode(string authorizationCode)
    {
        AuthenticationResult aa;
        
        aa = await _app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(_scopes, authorizationCode).ExecuteAsync();
                  
        return aa;
    }
```

Below is the result when we get the access token with authorization code from B2C authorization endpoint.

[Screenshot where access token is NULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScTT7.png)

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275609/no-access-token-returned-for-ad-b2c-user-when-requesting-microsoft-graph-delegat)*(I only quoted some of the comments below from the post)*

> Mass confusion here. You can definitely do what you are looking to do,
> except that this is all Azure AD functionality, not Azure AD B2C. So
> you are not looking to invoke any B2C user flow etc. B2C auths cannot
> get access to Microsoft APIs, only your own APIs.

> AAD tenant - contains only AAD endpoints. It is a single token issuer.

> B2C tenant - contains both AAD and B2C token endpoints. There are two
> token issuers respectively

> **You cannot use tenantName.b2clogin.com to obtain a token for MS Graph
> API**, based on the above rule set. This means a **users B2C
> authentication cannot be used to authorize to AAD protected apps, or
> Microsoft APIs.**

Based on the comments above, Is it really true that we cannot access the MS Graph from B2C application but we can only access when app is registered in AAD?

I am wondering since login.microsoftonline.com is already deprecated and microsoft advise to use b2clogin instead.

Please share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you still cannot do that from B2C apps, they need to use client credential flow with an AAD app registration + application permissions.

Comment: Hello. Does it mean we need to authenticate the user to AAD authorization endpoint and not in B2C authorization endpoint so that we can access MS Graph API? Thanks!

Comment: No, B2C users usually cannot authenticate on the AAD endpoint. Your app back-end would typically use client id + secret/certificate to call MS Graph API as the app, not as the user.

Comment: You can check instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga

Comment: My comments are spreading :D yes it’s still true. Use normal AAD flows to achieve your goal. My original comment also explained around deprecation point, it’s not relevant in this scenario either.

Comment: A B2C tenant contains:

AAD endpoint: login.microsoftonline.com THIS IS NOT BEING DEPRECATED
AAD B2C endpoint: tenantName.b2clogin.com+ B2C policyId parameter

Comment: Hahahha apologies :). In our scenario, we have a custom login policy, thus we need to reach the authorize endpoint: tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_signin_signup/oauth2/v2.0/authorize and receive the authorization code. Then we need to request access token to MS graph but it will not be possible due to the issue mentioned.

Comment: Is it possible in AAD? or do you have references about this? I have been checking this issues for a couple of days already and today I found your comment in other post about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot use the **Microsoft Graph API** to manage users in the Azure AD B2C directory. For B2C users, you generally use the **[Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api)** to perform CRUD operations.

please see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072756/microsoft-graph-rest-api-v1-0-access-to-b2c-tenant-users) and [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/526).

Comment: I am not sure but I get the list(and able to perform crud) of B2C users thru Microsoft Graph Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Query I run: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users

but I am not able to get thru our web app.