# Access Azure AD App resources with application in another tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

**Hello Everyone,**
I have an Azure AD application with MS Graph's authorizations for get users or calendars.
And i have a B2C tenant with an application and a user flow. the B2C authentification working well in my blazor app, but my B2C Application haven't access at MS Graph's authorizations from my AD Application.

I have trying to make custom scope and declare it in my B2C app or use API connector but nothing work.

I give you screenshots of my AD application and my B2C application:

My AD Application :

[API Exposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni6eA.png)

[API Authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMEn9.png)

If you have a solution or an idea to test...

Thank you in advance..

Comment: The two screenshots you provided are from AD, and AD tenants and B2C tenants are different. You cannot use applications in the b2c tenant to access resources in the AD tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Moving from Comments to Answer)

The two screenshots you provided are from AD, and AD tenants and B2C tenants are different. You cannot use applications in the b2c tenant to access resources in the AD tenant.

In addition, for Azure AD b2c applications, it cannot use MS Graph, but can only use AAD Graph, see: [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/526) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072756/microsoft-graph-rest-api-v1-0-access-to-b2c-tenant-users).